# Map from Torus to Projective Plane inducing an Epimorphism on Fundamental groups

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

> Is it true or false that there exists a continuous map from the torus to the projective plane inducing an epimorphism on the fundamental groups?

I am quite lost on this problem, what I know is that $\pi_1(T)=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, that $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2)=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, and that an epimorphism is a surjective homomorphism.

Let $f:T\to \mathbb{R}P^2$, I tried $f_*:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $f_*(x,y)=xy\pmod 2$ which is certainly surjective, but I am skeptical it fits the requirements of this question.

Comment: There is a map from the torus to the circle which is subjective on fundamental groups and there is a map from the circle to the projective plane which is subjective on fundamental groups, because the fundamental group of the latter space is cyclic.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez thanks, is this a theorem?

Comment: You might like to look at Ellis, G.J. "Homotopy classification the J. H. C. Whitehead way". Exposition. Math. 6~(2) (1988) 97-110., for which a version is available at http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/pdffiles/ellis.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the comment:

$(1)$ Find a continuous map $f : \mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb S^1 \to \mathbb S^1$ so that $f_*$ is surjective.

$(2)$ Let $\gamma : \mathbb S^1 \to \mathbb{RP}^2$ represent the generator of $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^2)$. Then $\gamma_*$ is surjective.

$(3)$ The composition $\gamma \circ f$ is one of the example as $(\gamma\circ f)_* = \gamma_* \circ f_*$ is surjective.